# Obtener precio producto Amazon

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Estoy intentando obtener el precio de un producto Amazon y no consigo obtener el resultado del tag (priceblock_ourprice) donde debería de estar la información.
Por ejemplo:

```
URL='https://www.amazon.es/dp/B018KF44OO'
curl -v --silent $URL 2>&1 | grep "id=\"priceblock_ourprice\"" | awk '{split($0,a,">"); split(a[2],b,"<"); print(b[1])}'
```

También añadiendo cabeceras, pero el precio no lo obtengo

```
 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/28.0.1500.12 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25"
```

Alguien sabe si es posible obtener el precio de un producto? vía cURL o pasando a JSON con tan solo pasando el ID de un producto.

Gracias!

Comment: Ese producto en concreto no tiene precio. ¿Qué esperas conseguir?

Comment: @ChemaCortes Si tiene precio, 8,75€.

Comment: @Guif_if Si lo miras atentamente, veras que el precio viene dado por un script. curl te devuelve la pagina en plano, deberias usar algun programa de scraping para que carge la pagina, espere x segundos y hay puedes obtener el precio.

Comment: @Guif-if Ese precio no lo ofrece amazon (tag `priceblock_ourprice`). Son otras ofertas disponibles que sólo ves si estás registrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, como dicen los comentarios, tu producto no tiene precio, sin embargo te dejo un script de como puede capturar esos datos. He dejado tu producto, es el tercero de la lista, al final obtendrás el precio y el nombre para que lo puedas identificar.

```
PRODUCTS="
https://www.amazon.es/dp/B00HZTCTRQ
https://www.amazon.es/dp/B06XWGLLQH
https://www.amazon.es/dp/B018KF44OO
" 

for PRODUCT in $PRODUCTS; do
    PAGE_CONTENT=$( curl -sL -H "User-Agent: Chrome" "$PRODUCT" )

    PRICE=$( echo "$PAGE_CONTENT" |
        pup "#priceblock_ourprice text{}" |
        perl -nle 'print $1 if /([0-9,]+)/' |
        sed s/,//g
    )
    PRODUCT_NAME=$( echo "$PAGE_CONTENT" | pup "#productTitle text{}" | xargs )

    echo "$PRICE" "$PRODUCT_NAME"
done
```

Éxitos.

Comment: gracias. Me sirvió.